# Login Form HTML5 and jquery

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have created table in the database called student and a register form which is working to store database when student register.My problem is in the login form.How do i check whether the matric and password in the form matched with matric and password in the database.Thanks

```
 function createDB(tx){
              //  tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXIST hfu');
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS STUDENT (matric, name, password)');
        }

  }
  function insertDB(tx){
      var _matric=$("[name='matric']").val();
      var _name=$("[name='name']").val();
      var _password=$("[name='password']").val();
      var sql ='INSERT INTO STUDENT (matric, name, password) VALUES (?,?,?)';
      tx.executeSql(sql,[_matric,_name,_password],sucessQueryDB,errorCB);
  }

   function submitForm(){
      db.transaction(insertDB, errorCB);
      $.mobile.changePage("#page2",{reverse:false,transition:"slide"});
      return false;
   }

   function loginForm(){

   }

        </script>
```

```
<div data-role="page" id="page4" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form method="POST" onsubmit="return loginForm()" id="myForm2" data-ajax="false">

        <input name="matric" type="text" placeholder="Matric">
        <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Placeholder">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the insert, you need to do a select transaction to see if the value exists. The select result will be a resultset you can check the size of. If it is 0, do an insert, if it is 1, handle it however it makes sense to you (show an error to user or whatever).

Comment: sorry,typing error just now.Yes,i want to check if there exist a matric and password in the database.Then login success.If non exist then,output u have not register yet.Can i make var sql=SELECT * WHERE matric=_matric AND password= _password like that?

Comment: Yes, you can. I assume you mean, can I do dynamic SQL, and yep.

Comment: can u share the code because i'm getting SQL error when implement it in my system

Comment: I'm not going to write the code for you. You can share the code you tried and I can see if I can help you with it.

Comment: function checkDB(tx){
       var _matric=$("[name='matric']").val();
       var _password=$("[name='password']").val();
       var sql ='select * from STUDENT where matric='+_matric+' and password='+_password+'';
       tx.executeSql(sql,[_matric,_password],successLoginDB,errorCB);
       }

      function successLogin(tx,result){
       var len = results.rows.length;
       if (len==1) {alert("you logged in with some user");}
      }

Comment: You are not escaping the strings you are searching for. Your SQL ends up like this: select * from STUDENT where matric = bob. See how bob isn't escaped? Use bound parameters instead. See details in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/